# NodeJS: Reference the same variable in multiple modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, module

In node, I am creating an instance of a module that connects via websockets to slack. I do this with `const slackbot = new SlackBot()`. How do I set things up so that I can reference the same `slackbot` in a few different modules? Is the best way just to pass `slackbot` to module functions every time I want to call it within that module?

```js
const slackbot = new SlackBot();

someModule.doThing(data, slackbot)
.then((response) => {
  otherModule.doAnotherThing(response, slackbot);
})
.then((response) => {
  someModule.wrapUp(response, slackbot);
});
```

Comment: "Is the best way just to pass slackbot to module functions every time I want to call it within that module?" Yes. There are ways to make it a global, but they’re not good style.

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing is

```
/** slacbot.js */
const slackbot = new SlackBot();

someModule.doThing(data, slackbot)
.then((response) => {
  otherModule.doAnotherThing(response, slackbot);
})
.then((response) => {
  someModule.wrapUp(response, slackbot);
});

// getter    
var getSlackBot = function(){
  if(slackBot) return slackBot
  else {
    slackbot = new SlackBot();
    return slackbot;
  }
}

module.exports.getSlackBot = getSlackBot;


/** consumer.js **/
var slackBot = require('slackBot').getSlackBot();
```